# about GAE cpu instance configuration/performance

Tags: google-app-engine

I search on web but not got the clear answer.

```
Google App Engine free quota  
CPU Hours   -   6.5hrs/day
```

What is the CPU config?
I saw somebody said it is only 600M hz cpu, is it right?

Comment: Where di you get the 6.5 number? Its actually 28 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation

```
The default class for frontends is F1, which gives you 128MB of memory and 600MHz of CPU    capacity. You can change the class of the frontend using the performance settings in the admin console.
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

So by default its 600MHz but you can upgrade it and obviously it will increase you bill.